# Create Multiple 'Posts' lists in one SharePoint Web

Tags: sharepoint, blogs

Is it poosible to create multiple SharePoint lists in a single SharePoint web. We do not want to create seaparate sub-webs for each blog site. Any pointers on how to achieve this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done. The ContentType of the Posts list restricts that only one can be created per site.